# System of 6 harmonic oscillators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

I have seen this question in given  image many times in past few years. And everytime i see this question, i instinctively conclude that its has atleast three possible answers $π/3$ , $2π/3$ and $π$ .

The reason behind my conclusion is that i can compare this system of 6 harmonic oscillations with same frequency and amplitude and different phases, to a system of 6 vectors with equal magnitude originating from same point. To get the zero resultant vector in analogous case of 6 vectors, its very easy to imagine that angle between two consecutive vectors should be $π/3$ ,$2π/3$ or $π$. So in the case of 6 harmonic oscillations the phase difference between two consecutive oscillations should be $π$ , $2π/3$ or $π/3$.
I can mathematically prove this too and calculate its principal solutions.

But for some reason everywhere in saw the solution of this question , the answer given was always $2π$ . Which is a wrong answer according to me. This question was in one my exam too.  And in that exam too the answer in the official  answer key was $2π$ for some reason

Is my reasoning wrong? Or $2π$ is actually the only solution?

Comment: I agree with you. Another way to look at it is that we can have three pairs that each superimpose to zero: phase angles 0 and π, π/3 and 4π/3, and 2π/3 and 5π/3, which corresponds to answer (b).

Comment: Interestingly, an [online search](https://books.google.com/books?id=77kgEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=%22six+simple+harmonic+oscillations+each%22&source=bl&ots=M3O4ywLL5h&sig=ACfU3U3ve9MJX30fCK_TLxq9zUi5iGNM-g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjoooz2r4L1AhXsTN8KHQKbD4EQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22six%20simple%20harmonic%20oscillations%20each%22&f=false) for the text reveals another answer code that gives the answer as null (·) under the reasoning that only π can be a solution. They seem to be looking only at cancellation for consecutive waveforms, which is different from the original question.

Comment: Stop worrying; you're right, and $2\pi$ is manifestly wrong.  ($\Delta\phi=2\pi$ would put all the oscillators *in phase*, interfering *constructively*.)

Comment: @Chemomechanics Phase angle 0 is not a solution (anymore than $2\pi$ !) Moreover, I would have grouped $\pi/3$ with $5\pi/3$  which are equivalent (essentially answer (b) ), and $2\pi/3$ with $4\pi/3$ which are also equivalent, but not equivalent to the two others and thus not to answer (b).

Comment: @Alfred I did not say that 0 is a solution. My comment, which I think you've misinterpreted, describes another way to see that π/3 is the only solution in the list of available answers.

Comment: @Chemomechanics OK, I understand now what you meant, sorry. However, though it is indeed a proof that $\pi/3$ is a solution, you have not disproved the other three that are proposed.

Comment: I'll rephrase in case it's clearer: Only answer (b) gives six waveforms containing three pairs of perfectly out-of-phase waveforms. That's a simple visual way to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

Any configuration for which the resulting amplitude equals zero requires the complex sum

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^5 \exp(\imath\phi_n)=0
\end{equation}
with  imaginary unit $\imath$.

As we have $\phi_{n+1}=\phi_n+\Delta\phi$ for $n\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, we obtain
$$\sum_{n=0}^5 \exp(\imath\phi_0) \exp(\imath n \Delta\phi)=0$$
and thus
$$\sum_{n=0}^5 \exp(\imath n \Delta\phi)=0$$
which is satisfied for $\Delta \phi = \pi/3$ but not for the other three options you specify. In particular, as already pointed out by Buzz, $\Delta \phi = 2\pi$ would yield all oscillators with identical phase, so they would have zero *phase* only at one moment in time and not zero amplitude.

The images below illustrate $\exp(\imath \phi_n)$ with $\phi_n=n\Delta_\phi$ and
$\Delta \phi \in\{\pi/6,\pi/3,\pi/2, 2\pi, 2\pi/3\}$.

[image: Phases represented on unit circle.]

Note that for $\Delta \phi =\pi/2$, the two phases at zero and $\pi/2$ occur twice, whereas at $\Delta \phi =3\pi/2$ each phase occurs exactly twice. Thus, out of the given solutions, only $\Delta \phi =\pi/3$ satisfies the condition of zero amplitude. Another independent solution is $\Delta \phi =2\pi/3$. Yet another solution $\Delta \phi =\pi$ has been mentioned by the OP. All of the solutions are trivially extended by adding integer multiples of $2\pi$, e.g.  $\Delta \phi =\pi/3+k\times 2\pi$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You convincingly proved that among the **proposed** answers, only $\pi/3$ is correct. However, you claim that (up to trivial additions of multiples of $2\pi$ ) the **only** other independent solution is $2\pi/3$, while the OP correctly **also** mentioned $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I updated my answer.